# Do you know why the named bag messages are not appearing?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that has a form with a select menu and if there are some validation errors in that form the validation errors are shown using `"@include('includes.errors')`". But in this same page I have a button that when the user clicks in it it shows a modal where the user can introduce a subject, a message to send an email. In this modal I also have "`@include('includes.errors')`".

**Issue:** So the issue is that if there are validation errors in the form in the modal because the subject or messare were not filled by the user that errors appear on the modal but also on the same page above the form that has the select menu. Also if there are some validation errors in the form that has the select menu and the user opens the modal that validation erros also appear in the modal.

To fix this issue using named bags is not working. For example in the `storeQuantities()` there is:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
{
     $validator = $request->validate([
        'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
    ]);

    // dd('test'); dont shows 

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'quantitiesError');
    }
    ...

}
```

In the contactOrganizer:

```
public function contactOrganizer($id, Request $request)
   $validator =  $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
    // dd('test'); dont shows 
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'contactErrors');
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
 @include('includes.errors', ['errors' => $errors->quantitiesError])
```

And in the modal:

```
@include('includes.errors', ['errors' => $errors->contactErrors])
```

But its not working it appears always that the bag is empty in both cases with "`{{dump($errors->contactErrors)}}`"  and  "`{{dump($errors->quantitiesError)}}`" like:

```
"MessageBag {#336 ▼
#messages: []
#format: ":message"
}"
```

It seems that the issue is because there is some error in "`$validator =  $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);`", any code after this line like "`dd('test);`" dont appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel will automatically redirect the user back to their previous location when `$this->validate` is used

You need to use `Validator::make` instead [Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators)

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
]);
if ($validator->fails())
    // redirect with errors
}
```

And don't forger to include `use Validator;`

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to achieve the same result in the contactOrganizer() where I use this approach to validate "$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);" ?

Comment: Like this: $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $customMessages); but you need to defined $rules and $customMessages arrays